# Access PhotoStream programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to access ones PhotoStream from OS X programmatically?

I didn't see any APIs and iCloud is just for application level storage.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the folder `~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets/sub` for all the images on the mac.